# Access $root instance from vuex actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Loader component in which it will execute based on

```
created() {
    this.$root.$on('show-loading', (vars) => {
        this.loading = vars;
        console.log('loader executed');
    });
},
```

Currently from a vue component i can execute `show-loading` through `this.$root.$emit('show-loading', true);`.

However, I am trying to execute the code now from my vuex module file. I get an error of

> TypeError: "_this.$root is undefined"

Anyone knows the proper way of accessing the root instance from vuex?

Comment: If the event is intended to set a variable in root, you could just use Vuex state, and bind to it from the root component. This decouples the root from your Vuex module.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not include but no the event doesn't set a root variable. `this.loading` is a component level data.

Comment: You could still use Vuex state for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put event handlers in the Vuex store. They do not belong there, and they will never work as expected. In the store you have getters (ways of getting values out of your store), mutations (synchronous setters), actions (asynchronous setters) and the state (your data).

Listeners belong on a Vue instance, such as a component. Other than that I would also suggest avoiding `this.$root` and `this.$parent` like the plague. Having these in your code commonly suggests that you are changing components outside their actual component files, which causes magic behaviour where things change where you do not expect them to change.

In your case what you want to do can much more easily be done with a single store mutation or action.

In your store create a mutation

```js
const mutations = {
  showLoading(state, data) {
    state.loading = data;
  }
};
```

Now in your component just use `this.$store.commit('showLoading', true);`. No event bus needed. No events that magically turn up in the root component. Just a single synchronous setter.

---

If you need to have global event handling you can instead use a bus.

```js
const $bus = new Vue();

Vue.prototype.$bus = $bus;
```

In components you can listen to events with `this.$bus.$on(...)` or emit events with `this.$bus.$emit(...)`. If you need to do stuff outside of Vue entirely, you can create event listeners outside of a component using the following pattern.

```js
$bus.$on('show-loading', (vars) => {
    // Do something
});
```

Technically it would allow you to even load the store with `import store from '../path/to/store'` and `store.commit(...)`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will have a try with your method and give you my feedback